# Stripe application fees via the W3C Web Payments API

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

Stripe provide [Web Application Fees](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#collecting-fees) payment functionality to their merchants/customers via a native bespoke API. Is there anyway other than this [feature request](https://github.com/w3c/payment-handler/issues/335) to surface the functionality via the [Web Payments API](https://www.w3.org/TR/payment-request/)?

Answer (score 0):

Although Stripe does fully support the [Payment Request API](https://stripe.com/docs/payment-request-api), quite a lot needs to be done before you could use it to process Stripe Connect application fees. Firstly the W3C would need to agree on a spec (a lengthy process in itself), then they'd have to build the functionality. Finally Stripe would need to integrate it with Connect on their end.

For now I'd look to using Stripe's API to accomplish this, as it might be some time before it can be done with the Payment Request API.

Answer (score 0):

Great news!

@adrianhopebailie has detailed a solution right [here](https://github.com/w3c/payment-handler/issues/335#issuecomment-492603458) right now for Web Payment Disbursement functionality that requires no (absolutely **ZERO**) changes to the Payment Request *OR* Payment Handler APIs and W3C standards! (Always a bonus :-)

As he correctly points out, the methodData argument is opaque and pretty much down to the autonomous Payment Handler to specify. So Stripe, Square, and PayPal are free to specify to their customers the format/naming-convention for communicating Application Fees between Web App supplier and Stripe.

To quote Adrian's example: -

```
const methodData = [
  {
    supportedMethods: "https://square.com/",
    data: {
      parties: [{ 
        merchantId: "super-mini-cabs",
        portion: 0.1
      },{ 
        merchantId: "driver-fred",
        portion: 0.9
      }],
    },
  },
  {
    supportedMethods: "https://stripe.com",
    data: {
      application_fee_amount: 1.00,
    },
  },
  {
    supportedMethods: "https://paypal.com",
    data: {
      payouts: [{ 
        paypalId: 12478764,
        amount: 1.00
      },{ 
        paypalId: 23448764,
        amount: 9.00
      }],
    },
  },
];
```

Just tell us Paul/Stripe what you need us to tell you and it's done!